# count digit until you get number of digits you want

Tags: c, digits

I'm new to coding. I'm now learning C programing. I'm having a problem with counting digits. My objective is to only accept a fixed number of digits in the input. For example I want user to input only 7 digits number, so when they input anything else than a 7 digits number, the program should ask them to input again until it gets 7 digits number. Here is my attempt:

```
int n, count = 0;
printf("Please enter number:");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n");

while (n != 0)
{
    n /= 10;
    count++;
}

printf("%d", count);
if (count != 7)
{
    printf("You can use only 7 digits numbers");
}
```

Comment: You are not asking user again to enter number. Hint: Use some loop statements.

Comment: There's an easier way to do this.  What is the smallest and greatest seven digit number?

Comment: Should 0000256 be considered a 7 digit number? What about 000001234567?

Comment: 0000256 is a zero padded three digit number. 000001234567 is a zero padded seven digit decimal number. :)

Comment: The *serial* number (or pin code number) 0123456 has 7 digits :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by creating a small function to check the number of digits in the number entered for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_digit(int n){
    int count = 0;

    if(n == 0) return 1;

    while(n != 0)
    {

        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
int main(void) {
    int num;
    printf("Please enter number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);


    while (count_digit(num) != 7){
        printf("Please enter only 7digits number:\n ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

    printf("The 7digit number you entered  is: %d",num);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This counts 0 as a 0-digit number. Use a do-while instead and move the test to the end of that.

Comment: did you try it before, because when you enter 0000098 is not a 7, using do while is the same thing and this works already

Comment: `count_digit(0)` returns 0, but it should return 1. There's no 0-digit numbers.

Comment: @potrzebie i got your point, thanks for the hints, and i updated my answer now. sorry i couldn't get you at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[1000]; //Enter the maximum number of digits you expect as array size
    printf("Please enter number: ");
    scanf("%s", s);
    while(strlen(s)!=7)
    {
        printf("%d\n", strlen(s));
        printf("You can use only 7 digits numbers\n");
        scanf("%s", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After taking the input, you can easily convert it to int if you need to.